# Phonegap Android: How to open whitelisted domain urls in a new browser window?

Tags: android, cordova, whitelist

I am developing a iOs & Android App with Cordova 1.9 + JQM.

The app reads data from JSON services in "www.example.com", so I have this domain whitelisted in cordova.xml

The problem is I need to open some URL pointing to www.example.com in a new browser window, outside the app.

I tried these:

```
<a href="#" onclick="navigator.app.loadUrl('http://www.example.com/external')"
   class="ui-link" rel="external" target="_blank">external</a>

<a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://www.example.com/externa')"
   class="ui-link" rel="external" target="_blank">external</a>

<a href="http://www.example.com/external"
   class="ui-link" rel="external" target="_blank">external</a>
```

...but all of them open the new window inside the webView, not in a native browser new window. I made this work in iOS but can't see the solution for Android.

Any help would be appreciated. thanks!!

Comment: this https://build.phonegap.com/blog/access-tags clearly explains the situation, but Im not posting that as answer, because it doesnt work for me as described there, either :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two ways to do this:

1. Use `navigator.app.loadUrl("http://www.example.com/index.html", {openExternal: true});`
2. Use the [ChildBrowser](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/ChildBrowser) Plugin and it's openExternal command.

Comment: Adding {openExternal: true} was the gamesaver in my case. Thank you so much.

Comment: {openExternal: true} no longer works in iOS with Phonegap 3.1.0 - all my links open within the webview. (Android still works correctly.)